# Changing class of another element on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm really stuck on this. I'm trying to have the background image of a container change into another after a click event. I have my code working fine in jsfiddle but I can't get it to work on Wordpress.

I think it might be because of the PHP but I've tested without it (using the exact jsfiddle code) to  no avail. If anyone could help point out why that would be awesomeeeee.

[Here's the code on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuHrJ/6/)

And here's the code that I'm using in my website

HTML snippet is in single-work.php:

```
<ul class="boom_boom_selector">
<?php 
  $images = get_custom_field('work_showcase:to_array', 'get_post'); 
  foreach($images as $img) {
?>
  <li class="boom_selector"><?php echo $img['post_content']; ?></li>
<?php  
  }
?>
</ul>

<div id="work_showcase" class="work_showcase">
</div> <!-- #work_showcase -->
```

JQuery in header.php:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.boom_selector').click(function(){
   $('#work_showcase').attr('class', $(this).text()); 
});
</script>
```

And the CSS also in header.php:

```
<?php
    $bg_color = get_custom_field('bg_work');
    $splash = get_custom_field('work_splash');
    ?>

        <?php /* prints .extra, .web, .print */
        $images = get_custom_field('work_showcase:to_array', 'get_post'); 
        foreach($images as $img) {
        ?>
    .<?php echo $img['post_content']; ?> {
        background-image: url("<?php echo $img[guid];?>");
    }
        <?php  
        }
        ?>

    ul.boom_boom_selector li {
        background-image: url(<?php echo $selector ?>); 
    }

    .work_showcase {
    background-image: url(<?php echo $splash ?>);
}


    </style>
```

Comment: Run it after the DOM is ready. Check @muthu's answer. And it's always better to post an example code instead of the code you are using for you real site/project.

Comment: Turns out that I just forgot to add the document ready function. I'm such a noob :(.

Thanks though guys! And @DeepakKamat I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script needs to run after the DOM is ready, so you need to put your code into `document` ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Do something with the DOM
   $('.boom_selector').click(function(){
     $('#work_showcase').attr('class', $(this).text()); 
   });
});
```

Or use the shorter version

```
(function(){
  // Do something...    
});
```

Comment: Gah. I'm so stupid. That was it, I spent like two hours trying to figure out the problem. Thanks so much!